# Grunt - Warning: path must be a string Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs

I've been using grunt for a long time and working fine. Now, suddenly, it arises a warning and abort the task when running the sftp deploy.

The warning is:

> Completed in 1.366s at Tue Aug 02 2016 21:36:06 GMT+0200 (CEST) - Waiting...
>   File "../build/footer.php" changed. Running "sftp-deploy:build" (sftp-deploy) task Warning: path must be a string Use --force to
>   continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

What's wrong? I have not changed gruntfile.js.

Comment: One of the directories you're trying to use in your build doesn't exist... check on that. Might be able to help more if you post your grunt config.

Comment: All directories exists.

Comment: Sorry, but that's simply not true. That's what the error means: it's trying to find a path that does not exist. If you want help you need to provide more information: like your grunt config.

Comment: @jakerella at least I could find the error. The variable 'cache' were changed to true by mistake. Once changed to false, all came to normality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comments, here's what may have been happening: The `cache` option "remembers" paths... so what might have happened is it "remembered" your build path, even though that build path may have been destroyed and recreated. If a directory is cached, then deleted, then another directory with the same name is created, those two directories are **not** the same, and when your task `sftp-deploy` task looked for the directory, it was actually looking for the old one. The new one, though it had the same name, was technically a different file entry in the operating system.